# Docker Bad owner or permissions on /root/.ssh/config

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ssh, permissions

So, I've set up `docker 17.03` on `Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS`. The problem is, the application needs to `ssh` to an external server. Since `docker` binds current users `ssh` files, it should allow me to `ssh` into the server from the container. However its giving me the `Bad owner or permissions on /root/.ssh/config` error.

From what I've figured, docker is running as my ubuntu user which is `1001` and is trying to access `root` account `ssh` files (I could be wrong) which is why its giving me this error.

Also, when I run `echo $USER` from the container, its not returning any user, but just an empty line.

The question is, has anybody faced this problem before and if so, has anybody solved it?

Comment: Hi, Vilius
Do you find a solution? I have exactly the same problem and could not find out how to solve it.

Comment: @PaulZakharov, No, unfortunate I have not. However I do know a dodgy workaround. You could add root user ssh key to an external server authorised keys, and this would allow you to connect to the server

Answer (score 13):

On Linux,
Changing the ownership to root fixed the issue for me.
I also added my usergroup as group, so the config will work outside docker as well.

```
chown root:$USER ~/.ssh/config
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/config
```

Answer (score 7):

These commands should fix the permissions issues:

Set the file owner:

```
chown $USER ~/.ssh/config
```

Set rw for user only permissions on config:

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
```

If `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config` doesn't work try with:

```
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/config
```

Comment: Is that inside the docker container or my host machine? The first command fails because $USER returns `NULL`. The second two return `chmod: changing permissions of '/root/.ssh/config': Read-only file system`. That is if I run the command inside the dcoker container

Comment: Set It un the host machine

Comment: Still same message :-(

Answer (score 1):

The following solution has worked for me: https://github.com/welaika/docker-wordmove/pull/17

This uses an entrypoint script to copy the contents of the mounted .ssh directory to /root/.ssh and adjusts the ownership and permissions. I modified the script for the ticket slightly to skip the *.pub files which caused a problem when absent.

mount-ssh.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

# Using `-v $HOME/.ssh:/root/.ssh:ro` produce permissions error while in the container
# when working from Linux and maybe from Windows.
# To prevent that we offer the strategy to mount the `.ssh` folder with
# `-v $HOME/.ssh:/.ssh:ro` thus this entrypoint will automatically handle problem.

if [[ -d /.ssh ]]; then

  cp -R /.ssh /root/.ssh
  chmod 700 /root/.ssh
  chmod 600 /root/.ssh/*
  if compgen -G "/.ssh/*.pub" > /dev/null; then
    chmod 644 /root/.ssh/*.pub
  fi
  chmod 644 /root/.ssh/known_hosts

fi

exec "$@"
```

In the Dockerfile:

```
[..]
COPY mount-ssh.sh /bin/mount-ssh.sh
[..]
RUN chmod +x /bin/mount-ssh.sh
[..]
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/mount-ssh.sh"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that what you are doing is:

```
docker run -v ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh alpine:3 -it --rm sh -c "apk update && apk add openssh && ssh any-available-ssh.example.com"
```

The easy solution is:

```
docker run -v ~/.ssh/id_rsa:/root/.ssh/id_rsa -v ~/.ssh/known_hosts:/root/.ssh/known_hosts alpine:3 -it --rm sh -c "apk update && apk add openssh && ssh any-available-ssh.example.com"
```

Explanation: the `.ssh/config` file does not exist by default on most distros. It seems that OpenSSH is treating this one file differently than the rest (differently than `.ssh/id_rsa` which has more lax permission checks). Therefore any way that removes only that one file `.ssh/config` from consideration is going to work.

Caveat emptor: I assume you use `.ssh/id_rsa` for authentication, but there are other possibilities, such as the more modern `.ssh/id_ed25519`. Adjust this name manually.

Answer (score 0):

I have a single user Linux machine that shares the same '.ssh' directory with the root account. The /root/.ssh is a symbolic link that points to the user's '/home/username/.ssh' folder.

I only recently added a ~/.ssh/config file and this caused SSH to give me the error message when invoking SSH and SSHFS from the root account. The solution for me was to do the following:

```
chown root:$USER ~/.ssh/config
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/config
```

This is a bit of a problem when I have to edit the file though, since it requires me to mess with the permissions and ownership of the file, then flip them back. But that is my own problem because I choose to share the folder between the accounts. I created some shell scripts to flip the permissions around only when invoking the 'sshfs' or 'ssh' command from using the root user account.